# AngularJS + WebStorm Tutorial faulty error highlighting?

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

I am trying to follow the Angular2 tutorial here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html.

The problem I encounter is that even though I copied the whole source code from the tutorial page WebStorm is highlighting the source code as if there was an error....

It all seems to go wrong when adding the directives to the component decorator:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>My Heroes</h2>
    <ul class="heroes">
        <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
            [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
            (click)="onSelect(hero)">
            <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
        </li>
   </ul>
   <my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
  `,
styles: [`
],
directives: [HeroDetailComponent],
providers: [HeroService]
})
```

So after all what WebStorm displays looks like this:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Unclear. What is the error message?

Comment: in youer settings you need to specify the javascript version to use ECMAScript 6: Preference>Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript> JavaScript Language Version

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon that is not ES6. It's Typescript.

Comment: yea you are right maybe, did not watch carefulluy enough, but still switching to harmony and installing the typescript pluging should help

Comment: @Uwe what version of WS are you using and is the file .js or .ts?

Comment: it is a bug. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22139 . Fixed in WS2016.2 beta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@anstarovoyt

Thanks for that bug comment - you are right.

Following your link [youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22139](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22139)

I found a suitable work around for now.

```
let HeroDetailComponent: any[] = [
    HeroDetailComponent
];
```